# Parametrizing type in Java (GADT)

Tags: java, generics, gadt

I need to have so sort of GADT in Java, like

```
interface Action<C, O> {
    Collection<O> doAction(C<O> predicate)
}
```

so I can easily declare class like

```
class Selector<T> {
...
}
```

and then use it with implementation of Action accepting instance of Selector for example. And having the implementation of Action accepting Predicate as well - but type of argument must match return type of collection.

The main idea is to have one type dependent on another one. Is that possible in plain old Java 6?

Comment: I'm not sure that I follow. You could define `Action` as `Action<O, C<O>>`, I think (although you might as well use `C` for the type of `predicate`). Java, like most languages, doesn't support higher order types.

Comment: @TomHawtin-tackline Action<C,C<O>> is not valid definition.

Comment: You cannot only because C is a generic you cannot guarantee that C is a generic type of O.  You can specify that C extends from a particular class or implements a specific interface which can contain O. Can you provide more information on C,O?

Comment: `Action<O,C<O>>`. Er, yes. `interface Action<C, O> { Collection<O> doAction(C predicate); }`.

Answer (score 0):

This doesn't work because there's nothing enforcing that `C` in `Action<C, O>` is, itself, a parameterized type. You could declare an `Action<String, Object>` for instance -- and then what is `predicate` supposed to be? There's no such thing as `String<Object>`.

Without knowing more details, it looks to me as though what you want is something more specific, e.g., define a `Predicate<T>` interface:

```
interface Predicate<T> {
}

interface Action<C extends Predicate<O>, O> {
    Collection<O> doAction(C predicate);
}

class Selector<T> implements Predicate<T> {
}
```